# How to get current location on google maps in kotlin using fusedlocation

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I used last location from FusedLocationClient to get location on map. How can i get current location?

I have seen code samples where current location appears in fused location client object

The current location option is not available here in the fusedlocationproviderclient object as it is supposed to be.

How can i get current location?

```
class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
    private lateinit var currentLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private var permissionCode = 101

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.


        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        getCurrentLocationUser()
    }

    private fun getCurrentLocationUser() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    !=(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this , android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                !=(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this , arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            , permissionCode)
            return
        }

        

          fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->

             if (location != null){
                 currentLocation = location
                 Toast.makeText(applicationContext , currentLocation.latitude.toString() + "" + currentLocation.longitude.toString()
                 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                 val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                     .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
                 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
             }
         }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when(requestCode ){
            permissionCode -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getCurrentLocationUser()
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
      val latLng = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude , currentLocation.longitude)
        val markerOPtions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location")

        googleMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
        googleMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f))
        googleMap?.addMarker(markerOPtions)
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided seems to be working fine after running in my own environment. Can you please clarify what's your expected result? Or what specific issue you are really having? And how to reproduce it?

Comment: i found the issue. My gms location dependency was not of current version. Thanks for help